# Get something over to somebody?

Tags: british-english

I am watching The Office (UK) to improve my English. In the beginning of EP1, the actor said "We'll get a CV over to you this afternoon". I guess he will send the CV to another person. Is there any difference between the way he talks and just a simple sentence "I will it send to you" ? I googled it but not much result about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the CV will arrive at its destination sometime in the afternoon but that the means by which it will get there is not specified. It may be *sent* by courier but it may be *taken* there by the speaker in person or a member of his team in which case it will have been 'taken' or 'brought' rather than 'sent'. However it will still have been 'got there'.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight difference between the two.

"We'll get a CV over to you this afternoon"   - promises that the item will arrive this afternoon.

"I will it send to you" - only says that the item will be sent. It makes no promise as to arrival time. Depending on delivery method, it might take several days.